# Why am I not able to install pygame on my PC?

Tags: python

I did everything by placing path on environment variables.

Then I run the following command:

```
pip install pygame
```

Now it is showing the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using 
'"c:\program files\python\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\pip.exe" install pygame': 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: It seems like you haven't installed pip properly. Check if you have added pip to your path (which should be the case if python is running) and if you correctly installed pip.

Comment: Are you using any kind of virtual environment? You should by the way.

Comment: it shows strange command `python.exe pip.exe ...` so i tries to run `pip.exe` as argument for `python.exe` but it should run `pip.exe` as any .exe program. You could also check if full paths are correct - check if exists file `c:\program files\python\python.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\pip.exe`. And last idea - it treats this line as one long program name - and it may need it as list `['"c:\program files\python\python.exe"',  '"C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\pip.exe"', 'install', 'pygame']`. This could means mistake in `pip` file.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is due to python version set on your Environment Variables.
Check `PATH` (or `Path`) for both System and Client variables.

If its pointing to `"path/to/python-installation/Python3.x-32"`,
change it to `"path/to/python-installation/Python3.x"`

Again check value on both System and Client Environment Variables

**Or**

Just upgrade your `pip` package by running below command.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```